# Swift, store and use CBPeripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I would like to call an action from the app delegate when the device is in background. The action is connecting to a Bluetooth device. Now, can I scan for Bluetooth Devices in a ViewController and store them as a CBPeripheral somehow to access them from the appdelegate?
Here's the action I'd like to fire from the Appdelegate. It's a action in a local notification. So I can only set it up in the Appdelegate. "specificperipheral" should the variable for the stored the CBPeripheral:

```
let key = self.keys[0]
let mac = key.lockMACAddress!
guard let specificperipheral = self.locks[mac] else {
    print("No peripheral found")
    return
}

// Perform an unlock operation. You may also attach an onComplete handler.
lockDevice?.performUnlock(specificperipheral, key: key).onCompletedAndDisconnected({ (data) -> () in
    print("Finished")
}).onFail({ (error) -> () in
    print("Error")
})
```